# on Inset faces tool, what edge rail do?

Tags: modeling, faces, tools

I don't think I follow

[image: Inset Face tool]

Nothing is happening.

Comment: They explain it in _this video_ at the 2:44 mark - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la4ai5JKpPw